# Client needs custom CacheStore that is configured on server

Tags: ignite

I have a client/server test that uses a custom CacheStore implementation.  I want the custom CacheStore on the server nodes but not on the client nodes, but Ignite is trying to load the custom implementation on the client.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Server code:

```
IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);
CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("test");
cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
cacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(new CacheStoreFactory());
IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

CacheStore:

```
public class CacheStoreFactory implements Factory<CacheStore<? super String, ? super String>> {
    @Override
    public CacheStore<? super String, ? super String> create() {
        return new CacheStoreAdapter<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String load(String key) throws CacheLoaderException {
                System.out.println("load: key=" + key);
                return key;
            }
            @Override
            public void write(Entry<? extends String, ? extends String> entry) throws CacheWriterException {
            }
            @Override
            public void delete(Object key) throws CacheWriterException {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Client:

```
IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
igniteCfg.setClientMode(true);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);
CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("test");
IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
String value = cache.get("someKey");
```

The CacheStore is called correctly on the server, and the client appears to work, but the client logs this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dalsing.ignite.server.test.CacheStoreFactory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache store on the client is required for `TRANSACTIONAL` caches. For `ATOMIC` caches (this is the default mode), it's not needed, so you can safely ignore the exception.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ignoring exceptions, since an exception indicates something wrong, usually fatal.  A warning maybe, but not an exception.  Is there no way to avoid the exception?  Also, if I wanted the cache to be transactional, the client would need the CacheStore.  What if the client was running in a microservice?  Would the CacheStore be called on the client?  I wouldn't want that.

Comment: It's actually needed not on the client, but on the node that executes a transaction, which can be either server or client. To guarantee transactional consistency you need to pair a cache transaction with a store transaction, so all updates have to come from the same node. Having said that, you can't update the store from primary nodes (which are always servers) like it's done in atomic cache.